# Introductory texts / papers for learning bare phrase structure?

Tags: syntax, phrase-structure, textbooks

My introductory syntax class is currently covering bare phrase structure. Unfortunately, we're using *An Introduction to Syntactic Analysis and Theory* which (while covering morphology, constituency, X'-theory, and a whole lot else in fair depth) does not cover modern bare phrase structure, and I could use some supplemental reading.

Where can I learn about bare phrase structure? Do introductory texts exist, or is it new enough to be only laid out in papers? I would particularly like to get a better handle on vP shells, I understand the motivation for them in terms of making our underlying structure simply *semantics* but their integration into the overall theory I am less confident about.

Comment: Who is the author of that work? Please provide an example of bare phrase. Thanks.

Comment: @apropros Complex stuff, includes Chomskyian theory etc.

Comment: This looks promising: https://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/display/document/obo-9780199772810/obo-9780199772810-0190.xml

Answer (score 2):

Coming back to this question: after talking with my professor, I can pretty confidently say that introductory texts do not exist. This set of notes from Nicholas LaCara at the University of Toronto is about the best thing that exists freely accessible on the internet: https://nlacara.github.io/teaching/331S18/331-7-bps.pdf

These notes do not incorporate formal features from the lexicon into the tree in the way that I have been taught to do in class, but are otherwise pretty comprehensive.

Comment: That's a pretty clear paper.